# Positioned absolute toggle element in flow with content below

Tags: html, css

`.menu` is `display: flex;` and on desktop devices has `justify-content: space-between;`
One of menu links toggles submenu and to make the submenu links not to break horizontal spacing of menu am using `position:relative;` for menu item and `position: absolute;` for submenu.

```
<hr>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a class="toggle" href="#submenu">submenu</a>
         <ul id="submenu" class="toggle-content">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> 
            </li>
            ...
         </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
<hr>
```

The problem is that below menu is `<hr>` and more content that should move down when submenu is open, but due to absolute positioning, submenu displays over the rest of content.

`<ul id="submenu">` is inside the `<ul class="menu">`, because as far as I know this is the right HTML semantic way of creating submenu. Any ideas of semantically valid manner to toggle submenu so that content below moves down when submenu is open?

Jsfiddle of the menu https://jsfiddle.net/virsis12/qgL1ejaf/21/

Thanks a lot in advance for using your brain power!

Answer (score 1):

Hello modify you html and css like this

```css
.toggle-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-content.is-visible {
  display: block;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 2.5rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 568px) {
  .menu {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

;
```

```html
<hr>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="#submenu">submenu</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="submenu" class="toggle-content">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">is simply dummy</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">text of</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">the printing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">and</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">typesetting industry</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</a>
  </li>

</ul>
<hr>
```

Comment: Appreciate your time! I am aware that placing submenu outside would solve the issue and to my mind I think if this is the only option then there is more to it. For example, maybe should add data attribute to all submenu li elements?

Comment: i get your point bro, definitely there are many other ways just as you said